# lodash: mapping array to object

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a built-in lodash function to take this:

```
var params = [
    { name: 'foo', input: 'bar' },
    { name: 'baz', input: 'zle' }
];
```

And output this:

```
var output = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 'zle'
};
```

Right now I'm just using `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```
function toHash(array, keyName, valueName) {
    return array.reduce(function(dictionary, next) {
        dictionary[next[keyName]] = next[valueName];
        return dictionary;
    }, {});
}

toHash(params, 'name', 'input');
```

Wondering if there's a lodash short-cut.

Answer (score 200):

Another way with [lodash 4.17.2](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#)

```
_.chain(params)
    .keyBy('name')
    .mapValues('input')
    .value();
```

or

```
_.mapValues(_.keyBy(params, 'name'), 'input')
```

or with `_.reduce`

```
_.reduce(
    params,
    (acc, { name, input }) => ({ ...acc, [name]: input }),
    {}
)
```

Comment: @Akrikos the `_.keyBy` will transform the entire array to an object, whereas the question is mostly about having one item from each object in array as key and one other item as its value. If `_.keyBy` is used, then all values will be objects.

Comment: Thanks @MustafaEhsanAlokozay You're right, that answer does not do the exact right thing. I'll delete my comment as it's not helpful. That may make your comment look weird, but better that than have my incorrect comment stay up any longer.

Comment: Anyone knows how to make this work with Typescript? is there a way to get object of output type with lodash?

Comment: For reduce, just use es6, zero point in lodash for this case. For Typescript, just put in the resulting type `balances.reduce<Record<string, AccountBalanceValue>>`

Comment: @vilemcech You'll have to cast the `accumulator` dictionary to get Typescript to be happy.  For this example, it would be: `{} as { [key: string]: string }`.

Answer (score 91):

You should be using _.keyBy to easily convert an array to an object.

[Docs here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy)

Example usage below:

```js
var params = [
    { name: 'foo', input: 'bar' },
    { name: 'baz', input: 'zle' }
];
console.log(_.keyBy(params, 'name'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If required, you can manipulate the array before using _.keyBy or the object after using _.keyBy to get the exact desired result.

Comment: Look first at this to understand most voted answer by stasovlas.

Comment: This is a cool answer, but it does **NOT** answer the question.  The values should be strings not objects.

Comment: is there a way to have it not convert key into string?

Comment: This does not answer the question since it does not return what is asked, namely: ```{ foo: 'baz', baz: 'zle' }```

Answer (score 43):

Yep it is [here](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce), using `_.reduce`

```
var params = [
    { name: 'foo', input: 'bar' },
    { name: 'baz', input: 'zle' }
];

_.reduce(params , function(obj,param) {
 obj[param.name] = param.input
 return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: Yet again `reduce()` swoops in with another use case. Smart way of doing it!

Comment: Anyone got the typescripted version of this?

Comment: The reality is that's mathematically true that you can implement literally any iteration action using reduce/inject, since reduce is isomorphic to a list. However, that flexibility comes with a price in readability.  Don't use `_.reduce` unless that accurately expresses what you're trying to do: it significantly obscures the point of the code in any other case. 

I personally prefer the `_.zipObject` solution by @djechlin -- failing that, the `_.keyBy`/`_.mapValues` approach.

Answer (score 26):

This seems like a job for Object.assign:

```
const output = Object.assign({}, ...params.map(p => ({[p.name]: p.input})));
```

Edited to wrap as a function similar to OP's, this would be:

```
const toHash = (array, keyName, valueName) => 
    Object.assign({}, ...array.map(o => ({[o[keyName]]: o[valueName]})));
```

(Thanks to Ben Steward, good thinking...)

Comment: Maybe wrap that in a parent function so the user can determine what keys would be used by passing them, like the OP had.

Comment: Thank you. This works well also if you want the value to be something else than input. For example, a boolean

Answer (score 14):

This is probably more verbose than you want, but you're asking for a slightly complex operation so actual code might be involved (the horror).

My recommendation, with [`zipObject`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zipObject) that's pretty logical:

```
_.zipObject(_.map(params, 'name'), _.map(params, 'input'));
```

Another option, more hacky, using [`fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#fromPairs):

```
_.fromPairs(_.map(params, function(val) { return [val['name'], val['input']));
```

The anonymous function shows the hackiness -- I don't believe JS guarantees order of elements in object iteration, so callling `.values()` won't do.

Comment: I don't see anything hacky about using `fromPairs`, and calling `values()` indeed won't do. At least from readability standpoint.

Answer (score 12):

You can use one liner javascript with [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method and [ES6 destructuring](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) to convert array of key value pairs to object.

```
arr.reduce((map, { name, input }) => ({ ...map, [name]: input }), {});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is O(n^2).

Comment: `arr.reduce((map, { name, input }) => (map[name] = input, map), {});` @jimrandomh what about this?

Comment: That version is O(n), but it modifies its input, which is something you usually don't want. I think for this sort of thing, it's generally better to write a full-length utility function with a foreach loop, put it in a utils folder out of the way somewhere and import it, rather than trying to be clever with one-liners.

Answer (score 7):

Another way with lodash

creating pairs, and then either construct a object or `ES6 Map` easily

`_(params).map(v=>[v.name, v.input]).fromPairs().value()`

or

`_.fromPairs(params.map(v=>[v.name, v.input]))`

Here is a working example

```js
var params = [
    { name: 'foo', input: 'bar' },
    { name: 'baz', input: 'zle' }
];

var obj = _(params).map(v=>[v.name, v.input]).fromPairs().value();

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: The good part of this solution is that it's also feasible in plain ES: `Object.fromEntries(params.map(v => [v.name, v.input]))`

Comment: @fregante, Chrome 73+ only https://caniuse.com/?search=fromEntries

Answer (score 7):

It can also solve without using any lodash function like this:

```
let paramsVal = [
    { name: 'foo', input: 'bar' },
    { name: 'baz', input: 'zle' }
];
let output = {};

paramsVal.forEach(({name, input})=>{
  output[name] = input;
})


console.log(output);
```

[image]